# How do I extract unique data from Hyperledger Composer using query or js

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to get unique data from a duplicates data at Hyperledger Composer. How can I achieve this?

suppose I have a data like this

```
     [
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "1",
 "dataType" : "in",
 "productName": "A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "2",
 "dataType": "in",
 "productName": “A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "BABA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "3",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "C",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "4",
 "dataType": "in",
 "productName": "C",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "5",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "B",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "BABA"
}
]
```

what I want to get is a list of unique Product name.

So the result I want maybe something like this

```
 [
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "1",
 "dataType" : "in",
 "productName": "A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "3",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "C",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "5",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "B",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "BABA"
}
]
```

I don't really care about the sequence. I just want to know what productName do I have in my database.

I think this needs something to do with the logic.js part. I can do queries and get the data using post method. But I don't know how to do that using logic.js

I don't know how to get the data from logic.js. The example at official page only delete or trade. They don't return a new data.

any help is appreciated. I want to know how to send data using the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js code to get the unique productname from your data would be

```
const data =[
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "1",
 "dataType" : "in",
 "productName": "A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "3",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "5",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "B",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "BABA"
}
];

const distinctProductName = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.productName))];
```

You will have your distinct ProductName in `distinctProductName` but you won't have the details of product. From your questions, it didnot feel necessary too. If you need the details too, you could do something like

```
const data =[
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "1",
 "dataType" : "in",
 "productName": "A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "3",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "A",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "GAGA"
},
{
 "$class": "org.stock.mynetwork.Commodity",
 "time": "5",
 "dataType": "out",
 "productName": "B",
 "quantity": 1,
 "country": "Unknown",
 "owner": "BABA"
}
];

const result = Array.from(new Set(data.map(x => x.productName)))
                    .map(productName => {
                             return{
                                    productName: productName,
                                    dataType : data.find(x => x.productName ===productName).dataType
                                   //you can obtain other values as I obtained dataType
                                   };
                              });
```

You will have your data in `result`.

Comment: after a few search, I found it

put @returns(String[])
at cto file

then 
return distinctProductName

and yes, you are right, I don't need the details for now